# Scale control on mapbox map

Tags: scale, mapbox

I try to add a scale control like that example https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/scale-control/ to my map. But I doesn't work like that and I can't find the error. Someone an idea?

here is my code:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'hashtagwinti.i0g0e0ai', { zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 4, minZoom: 2,maxBounds: [[-77.5175, -172.1666],[76.2295604,173.771]] } )
.setView([-38.00, -41], 4)
.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(argentina)
```

and I tried to add:

```
L.control.scale().addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of `argentina` defined elsewhere?

Unless you have shortened your code and omitted a variable declaration, your call to `setGeoJSON` is using an undefined variable.

Comment: yes it is defined as :
`var argentina = [{"features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[...]];`